# Project Organization

Tags: angularjs

Below I have shared my current directory structure for my AngularJS application that I have been rewriting from the first time I wrote it while I was learning the javascript framework. I have been revising this project structure to be more of a component-based application in case I need to further add new features to the project.

1. I currently have two index.html files and trying to figure out which one I should keep. Should keep the file existing in the public directory or should I keep the file inside of the src directory? Keep in mind that I have run a build script to create my app.css and app.js file.
2. In both index.html files, I have an ng-include file where I am attempting to load view partials and none of them are loading. I do not receive any javascript errors.

```
<ng-include src="../app/components/employees/views/form.html"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="../app/components/employees/views/stats.html"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="../app/components/employees/views/table.html"></ng-include>
```

[image: Current directory structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restructure my application and my build processes which easily removed the need for a public directory. By doing this I also was able to adjust the path to the partial files so they could render propertly.